# Unable to catch failed Records in Batch step Mule ESB

Tags: serialization, batch-processing, kryo, dataweave

**I have done the following configuration to my batch process.**

For batch Job  -->   max-failed-records=”-1”    - This indicates that the instance to process all the records irrespective of no. of records failing.

```
   1.   Batch_Step: AcceptPolicy=  “All”
             So this being first batch step will accept all the records and process them.

   2.   Batch_Step1: AcceptPolicy= “ONLY_FAILURES”
                So this must accept only the records that got failed in the first batch Step.


      **The first batchstep has some dataweave transformation.
    The second batchstep as of know i am just logging and no transformation  is present.**
```

The exception is happening in Dataweave, when some incorrect record(wrong data) comes, so this incorrect record must be captured in the second Batchstep.

But the issue I am facing is, first batch executes fine and shows the Count of failed records.

But the control is not coming to the second batch step at all, and PFB exception that is present in console. (This is happening only when some records are getting failed in the first BatchStep). For positive scenario, batch steps are working fine.  As per my observation, the following may be useful from the log console: Could not queue 4 records for instance '3b742880-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153' of job 'failedrecordspocBatch' on buffer 'batch-stepping-queue-buffer'. Records will be marked as failed. Processing block id is '3d066141-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153' . …. ..

```
The exception stack trace is 


    Cannot coerce a :null to a :string (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler:201 (null)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException: Cannot coerce a :null to a :string
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.StringFormatTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(StringFormatTypeCoercionValue.scala:58)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.StringFormatTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(StringFormatTypeCoercionValue.scala:14)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.stringops.JoinOpNode$$anonfun$evaluate$1.apply(JoinOpNode.scala:14)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2015-12-02 16:11:27,635 [batch-job-failedrecordspocBatch-work-manager.02] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.buffer.TransactionalQueueBuffer: Could not queue 4 records for instance '3b742880-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153' of job 'failedrecordspocBatch' on buffer 'batch-stepping-queue-buffer'. Records will be marked as failed. Processing block id is '3d066141-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153'
org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException: Could not serialize object
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer.serialize(AbstractObjectSerializer.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.AbstractBatchQueueDelegate.dispatch(AbstractBatchQueueDelegate.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.SteppingQueueDelegate.dispatch(SteppingQueueDelegate.java:52) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.buffer.TransactionalQueueBuffer.writeToQueue(TransactionalQueueBuffer.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.buffer.TransactionalQueueBuffer.doFlush(TransactionalQueueBuffer.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.buffer.TransactionalQueueBuffer.add(TransactionalQueueBuffer.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.routeNext(DefaultBatchEngine.java:736) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.routeError(DefaultBatchEngine.java:593) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine.updateStatisticsAndRoute(DefaultBatchEngine.java:817) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.threading.BatchRecordWork.run(BatchRecordWork.java:92) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_72]
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Serialization trace:
classes (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
classloader (java.security.ProtectionDomain)
context (java.security.AccessControlContext)
acc (org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader)
classLoaders (org.mule.module.launcher.application.CompositeApplicationClassLoader)
executionClassLoader (org.mule.DefaultMuleContext)
context (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.function.FlowRefLookupFunctionValue)
_2 (scala.Tuple2)
kv (scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1)
elems (scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap)
variableContext (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler)
payload (com.mulesoft.module.batch.record.Record)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:366) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:603) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:366) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.serialization.kryo.internal.KryoObjectSerializer.doSerialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.serialization.kryo.internal.KryoObjectSerializer.doSerialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer.serialize(AbstractObjectSerializer.java:64) ~[?:?]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.Vector$Itr.next(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_72]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:92) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:366) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:603) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:366) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:625) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.serialization.kryo.internal.KryoObjectSerializer.doSerialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.module.serialization.kryo.internal.KryoObjectSerializer.doSerialize(KryoObjectSerializer.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.serialization.internal.AbstractObjectSerializer.serialize(AbstractObjectSerializer.java:64) ~[?:?]
    ... 13 more
INFO  2015-12-02 16:11:27,635 [batch-job-failedrecordspocBatch-work-manager.02] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finished execution for instance '3b742880-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153' of job 'failedrecordspocBatch'. Total Records processed: 4. Successful records: 0. Failed Records: 4
INFO  2015-12-02 16:11:27,745 [batch-job-failedrecordspocBatch-work-manager.02] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: 
****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
*             - - + Exception Type + - -             *                  - - + Step + - -                  *                 - - + Count + - -                  *
****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
* com.mulesoft.module.batch.exception.BatchException * Batch_Step                                         * 1                                                  *
* org.mule.api.serialization.SerializationException  * Batch_Step1                                        * 4                                                  *
****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

INFO  2015-12-02 16:11:27,823 [batch-job-failedrecordspocBatch-work-manager.02] com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep: Step Batch_Step finished processing all records for instance 3b742880-98e1-11e5-9927-f0ea20524153 of job failedrecordspocBatch
```

However From the following link I came to know few of the payloads **cannot be serialized!!!**  This is the link:   http://bushorn.com/deeper-lock-mule-batch/

So, I understand I need to implement Kryo Serializer, which i was hearing for the first time.

So, Can some one help me how to implement **Kryo Serializer** concept in my batch step flow.

Please do comment in case of any clarification required.

Comment: And how is this linked to [tag:batch-file]??

Comment: Yes i have edited tags again